# JS Regex getting a pathname 'value' by 'key'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a pathname element, after a 'key' pathname, for instance, if I had the path which contained `'/colour/red'` then I'd like to be able to search for 'colour' and then get 'red'.

I'm trying to get '31' from the 'start' pathname. 
I've tried:

```
var url = 'http://myapp/html/live/index/start/31/sort/start_date'
if(/\/start\/([0-9]+)\//.test(url)) {
    alert(RegExp.$1);       
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong ? According to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ezxm9kd1/) it works as expected... I don't understand your question., if the value could be something else replace `[0-9]+` by `\w+` which will capture alphanumeric chars and _

Comment: You shouldn't use `test` and the global captures on `RegExp`. Instead, use the `match` or `exec` method.

Comment: Example non working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezxm9kd1/1/

Comment: @Kiksy You exemple is not working because you try to capture one CAPITAL letter followed by numbers `/\/sort\/([A-Z][0-9]+)\//` Correct one would be `/\/sort\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\//`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is right but `reged.test` only returns `boolean (true/false)`. You need to use `regex.exec` to get match array returns:

```
if (m = /\/start\/([0-9]+)\//.exec(url)) {
   console.log(m[1]); // 31
}
```

If you want to pass `start` as a dynamic string then use `RegExp` object:

```
var key = "start";
var re = RegExp("/" + key + "/([0-9]+)/");

if (m = re.exec(url)) {
   console.log(m[1]); // 31
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question--he wants to parameterize the "start" part.

Comment: @anubhava updated your example for `sort`, but can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/jv19q8mz/1/

Comment: Yes that is same as what I had in my 2nd example but you extended definition of `key` to be a word character instead of just digits. btw it can be simplified as: **`var re = RegExp("/" + key + "/(\\w+)/?");`**